# How do I use the value of a radio button to populate another value in my form dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, paypal

I have a paypal form that I want to dynamically change the email address in based on a radio button in the form. In other words, if one of the radio buttons is checked then the form would send one email address value and if the other was checked it would send another. Here is the sample code I have so far and what I've tried to do.

```
<form name="myform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@theaddress.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="item_name">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="60">
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="0" checked>Joe Bob
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="1">Hank
<input type="submit" src="img/ico/joinow.png" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
</form>
```

Once again, if someone selects JoeBob I want the email to be a different email address then if someone selected Hank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i+++){
 radios[i].onchange = function(){
  var email= document.querySelector("input[name='business']");
  if(this.value==0) // selected Joe Bob
   email.value= "email for Joe";
  }
  else{ // Selected Hank
   email.value= "email for Hank";
  }
}
```